# Не передаётся значение в фрагментный шейдер GLSL, при использовании функций OpenGL 4.6 SSO

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opengl, glsl

При попытке передать значение цвета в фрагментный шейдер, в юниформе отведённой под это, оказывается 0. Если не использовать SSO, то, всё работает правильно. Также, функция `glGetUniformLocation`, судя по её спецификации, в которой сказано:

> Эта функция возвращает -1, если имя не соответствует активной юниформ-переменной в программе, если имя начинается с зарезервированного префикса "gl_" или если имя связано с атомарным счетчиком или именованным юниформ-блоком.

отрабатывает без ошибок и возвращает 0. Соответственно, скорее всего, либо я неправильно использую функцию `glUniform*f`, либо как то не так создаю шейдерный конвейер. К сожалению информацию по этому поводу в интернете не нашёл.

Код фрагментного шейдера:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;
uniform vec4 ourColor;
void main()
{
color = ourColor;
}
```

Вот так создаю шейдерный конвейер:

```
std::uint32_t pipe;
glCreateProgramPipelines(1, &pipe);

std::uint32_t fprog = glCreateShaderProgramv(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1, &fragmentShaderSource);
std::uint32_t vprog = glCreateShaderProgramv(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, 1, &vertexShaderSource);

glCreateProgramPipelines(1, &pipe);
glBindProgramPipeline(pipe);

glUseProgramStages(pipe, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, fprog);
glUseProgramStages(pipe, GL_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT, vprog);
```

Цикл отрисовки:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    // Очистка окна...
    ...

    glBindProgramPipeline(pipe);

    GLfloat timeValue = glfwGetTime();
    GLfloat greenValue = (sin(timeValue) / 2) + 0.5;
    GLint vertexColorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(fprog, "ourColor");
    glUniform4f(vertexColorLocation, 0.0f, greenValue, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Отрисовка вершинного массива...
    ...
}
```

Comment: ¿`glGetError` никаких ошибок не сообщает?

Comment: Код ошибки после вызова glUniform4f: 1282

Comment: 1282 - это GL_INVALID_OPERATION. У Вас ourColor - vec4, а Вы передаете 4 float. Так нельзя делать, даже если сильно-сильно хочется.

Comment: Даже если создать массив: GLfloat color[4] = { 0.0f, greenValue, 0.0f, 1.0f };
И использовать glUniform4fv(vertexColorLocation, 4, color), то ошибка никуда не девается.

И так же я пробовал передавать в шейдер просто float переменную, через вызов glUniform1f, это то же не работает.

Comment: Возможно, ошибка где то ещё выше. Например, шейдер не компилируется или ещё что то. Я в таких случаях добавляю проверку на ошибки  (glGetError ) после каждого подозрительного вызова. У меня для этого просто макрос оформлен.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена использованием функции `glProgramUniform*f` вместо `glUniform*f`.